# Upgraded to MediaWiki 26 alpha, missing Assert

Tags: mediawiki

I try to upgrade to the newest alpha due some testing of extensions. But I get this error, and after Googling some time, I haven't been able to find it.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Wikimedia\Assert\Assert' not found in /var/www/MediaWiki/includes/libs/ProcessCacheLRU.php on line 132
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had forgot to run

```
composer update
```

I can extend this answer by saying you are running this in the prompt in the root directory of your installation. Read more on https://getcomposer.org/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It is the answer to the question.

Comment: The link no longer works, and I don't have any `composer` binary.

Comment: Sigh... This is a production machine. We don't have dev tools on it.

Answer (score 0):

Since WikiMedia 1.25, some modules were extracted out of the core to `vendor` directory, including the `assert` module. To plug these, add the following line:

```
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
```

When installing from Git, you may need to [clone another repository](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Download_from_Git#Fetch_external_libraries).